# Python code performing better on Win 10 vs. Mac OS

Tags: python, windows, macos, performance

I am fairly new to python but have been diving deeper and deeper in data analytics & ML applications, and been writing different scripts to process data and create forecasts.

In this particular instance, I have a code that replicates past data into the future before being processed further to develop forecast. The part I am particular interested in is python/pandas performance on Win 10 vs. Mac.

The data being processed is fairly large (approx 15-20M records x ~15 columns) so performance matters. I have a Mac machine with a 6 core i5 processor 3.0GHz cpu and 32GB ram, and another Win 10 machine with a 4 core (8 threads) 1.6GHz cpu and 16GB ram. On all benchmarks the mac should perform better and it does in many applications.

The script has two parts, a data generation part and a processing part. Using this script, the Win 10 performs way much better in the generating data part at 40 mins vs. 85 mins on Mac, while on the second part (processing) the performance is reversed where Win 10 takes 110 mins vs, only 77 mins on mac. The same also happens on another script with fairly similar application where Win 10 seems better at replicating/copying the data while the Mac is faster in processing it.

I did a lot of research and my understanding is that the Mac should perform better in most applications but not this one. Does anyone have any idea why? Is there any configuration on the Mac that needs to be done?

One thing to note, Windows uses only physical memory and times out if it runs out of memory while the mac uses a combination of both and rarely runs out of memory as it uses local cache if necessary.

*A few preceding lines are removed as they are unnecessary*

```
enter code here
*##data generator
starttime=datetime.datetime.now()
datestamp=datetime.datetime.now().date()
datestamp=str(datestamp)
#generate data for the period
DATE_RANGE=list()
Current_Date=NF_Startingdate
while Current_Date<=NF_Endingdate:
    DATE_RANGE.append((Current_Date,Current_Date.strftime(format='%A').upper()))
    Current_Date+=datetime.timedelta(days=1)
else: 'error'
    Forecast=pd.DataFrame(columns=        ['JRNY_DATE','OD_PAIR','CARD_TYPE','DAY_OF_WEEK','JRNY_START_15MIN_BAND','ORIGIN_LINE','ORIGIN_STATION','INTCHG1_STATION','INTCHG1_15MIN_BAND','INTCHG1_LINE','INTCHG2_STATION','INTCHG2_15MIN_BAND','DEST_STATION','DEST_LINE','JRNY_END_15MIN_BAND','PASSENGER_TRIPS','BASE_DATE'])
for d in DATE_RANGE:
    if (d[0]-DATE_RANGE[0][0])<datetime.timedelta(364):
    Forecast_d=df[(df['JRNY_DATE']==d[0]+datetime.timedelta(days=-364))]
    Forecast_d['BASE_DATE']=df[(df['JRNY_DATE']==d[0]+datetime.timedelta(days=-364))]['JRNY_DATE']
    Forecast_d['JRNY_DATE']=d[0]
    Forecast=pd.DataFrame.append(Forecast,Forecast_d,ignore_index=True,sort=False)
else:       
    Forecast_d=Forecast[(Forecast['JRNY_DATE']==d[0]+datetime.timedelta(days=-364))]
    Forecast_d['BASE_DATE']=Forecast[(Forecast['JRNY_DATE']==d[0]+datetime.timedelta(days=-364))]['JRNY_DATE']
    Forecast_d['JRNY_DATE']=d[0]
    Forecast=pd.DataFrame.append(Forecast,Forecast_d,ignore_index=True,sort=False)

#processing time
endtime=datetime.datetime.now()
processingtime=(endtime-starttime)/60
print('\n','generating data time  ',processingtime,'\n')
starttime=datetime.datetime.now()

#create additional columns to be used for growth and seasonality look up
Forecast['O_LINE_GROUP']=Forecast['ORIGIN_LINE'].apply(line_group)
Forecast['D_LINE_GROUP']=Forecast['DEST_LINE'].apply(line_group)
Forecast['TIME_PERIOD']=Forecast['JRNY_START_15MIN_BAND'].apply(time_period)
Forecast['WEEKDAY_WEEKEND']=Forecast['DAY_OF_WEEK'].apply(weekday_weekend)
Forecast['MONTH']=Forecast['JRNY_DATE'].apply(return_month)
Forecast['YEAR']=Forecast['JRNY_DATE'].apply(return_year)
Forecast['COMP_KEY']=Forecast.apply(lambda x: lookup_key(x['TIME_PERIOD'],x['WEEKDAY_WEEKEND'],x['O_LINE_GROUP'],x['D_LINE_GROUP']), axis=1)
Forecast['G_FACTOR']=Forecast.apply(lambda x: growth_factor_long(x['COMP_KEY'],x['MONTH'],x['YEAR']),axis=1)
Forecast['F_TRIPS']=Forecast['PASSENGER_TRIPS']*Forecast['G_FACTOR']
#export data
Forecast.to_csv(datestamp+'_Forecast_Output.csv', index = None, header=True)
#processing time
endtime=datetime.datetime.now()
processingtime=(endtime-starttime)/60
print('\n','Forecasting time  ',processingtime,'\n')*
```

Comment: I replaced dataframe with list of lists and seen better performance. Since you are dealing with 15-20m, would suggest to run with list of lists to check execution time. This may not be a solution for your issue. But, worth to see better performance even with your existing script.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll give it a go! Still curious on the difference in performance between both operating systems, I couldn’t find any other case like this anywhere on the web!